# How to prevent from overwriting using imagemagick

Tags: for-loop, imagemagick

noobie question:

i try to batch convert some files via imagemagick with

```
for i in *.jpg; do convert $i -colorspace Gray -rotate -90 -verbose out/%03d.jpg; done
```

it do convert the right way, but overwrites the output file on each loop instead of
continuing with the progressiv number intended with %03d.

```
input1.jpg=>out/000.jpg JPEG 2479x3508=>3508x2479 3508x2479+0+0 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 483KB 0.420u 0:00.339
input2.jpg=>out/000.jpg JPEG 2479x3508=>3508x2479 3508x2479+0+0 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 1.36MB 0.470u 0:00.390
input3.jpg=>out/000.jpg JPEG 2479x3508=>3508x2479 3508x2479+0+0 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 1.733MB 0.490u 0:00.410
input4.jpg=>out/000.jpg JPEG 2479x3508=>3508x2479 3508x2479+0+0 8-bit Grayscale DirectClass 2.806MB 0.560u 0:00.480
```

you see, its always overwriting 000.jpg

I need some hints to go forth...

dearest
lippe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
# Define a variable to increment 
counter=0
# Iterate over images
for image in *.jpg; do
  # Convert number from `1' to pretty format `001'
  printf -v pretty_counter "%03d" $counter
  # Convert image
  convert $image -colorspace Gray -rotate -90 -verbose out/$pretty_counter.jpg
  # Increment counter
  counter=$(( $counter + 1 ))
done
```

Or just

```sh
convert *.jpg -colorspace Gray -rotate -90 -verbose out/%03d.jpg
```

### Explanation

ImageMagick's [escape sequence](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#save_escapes) references the image stack. As your invoking the `convert` command inside the `for` loop, only one image will exist in the stack, and thus only file `out/000.jpg` will be generated. Solution would be to use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) to generate the output filename, or give `convert` the all files at once.

Comment: +1 By the way, plain `((counter++))` works just as well.